# How to make a button hidden in C# Xamarin IDE iOS

Tags: c#, ios, button, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do you make a button hidden in C# in the Xamarin IDE in iOS? I know this may be an easy question for some people but I have tried multiple ways and I can't get it to work probably.

I've used the code:

```
button1.Hidden = True;
button2.Hidden = True;
button3.Hidden = True;
```

and I've placed this code in the `viewDidLoad` section below

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();
    button1.Hidden = True;
    button2.Hidden = True;
    button3.Hidden = True;
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib. 
}
```

I've tried using `button1.Visible = false;` but that doesn't work either. I've tried placing it in different places in my view controller file and I still can't get it to work.  I've made sure that my buttons are corresponding with the names I am using in my file by naming them in the xamarin IDE.  What I'm trying to do is make my buttons disappear and reappear at the click of a button but I can't even get them to initially disappear.

Comment: I've also tried researching this online but have been unable to find a solution. I'm not sure if i'm placing the code in the wrong part of the file or if my syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/9317/how-to-hide-and-unhide-a-button

There is a very simple way to hide a button within Xamarin. Instead of using Button.Hide or Button.Hidden = true; You should go with

```
button.Visibility= ViewStates.Invisible;
```

This is essentially the same thing as Button.Hide(); or Button.Hidden = true;
It borrows from WPF development somewhat, where instead of the methods you used which would come from WinForm development, it would look like..

```
button.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```